# Prevent view object from jumping when moving with finger touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, touchesmoved

I've created a 200x200 circle in a custom UIView. I am using the following script to move the view object around the screen on the iPad.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{    
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

if([touch view] == newShape)
{
    newShape.center = currentPoint;
}

[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Everything works fine, I can move the circle anywhere on the screen. However, if I don't touch dead center on the circle object, it jumps slightly. By reading the code, this is quite obvious because `newShape.center` is being set to wherever the touch happens and ultimately snapping quickly to that position.

I'm looking for a way to move an object without snapping to the touch position. I'm thinking I would use xy coordinates to achieve this, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Thanks!

Comment: Off the top of my head (no code, on an iPhone) I think a simple if-then to figure out if your finger isnt dead center would work.  Just use that newShape.center line in a [UIView] animation block. (and seriously, script. LOL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `CGPoint prevPos;` in .h file.

Here my view is `_rectView`.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    prevPos = currentPoint;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if([touch view] == _rectView)
    {
        float delX =  currentPoint.x - prevPos.x;
        float delY = currentPoint.y - prevPos.y;
        CGPoint np = CGPointMake(_rectView.frame.origin.x+delX, _rectView.frame.origin.y+delY);
        //_rect.center = np;
        CGRect fr = _rectView.frame;
        fr.origin = np;
        _rectView.frame = fr;
    }

    //[self.view setNeedsDisplay];

    prevPos = currentPoint;
}
```

Use the above code. You will not get that 'jump' effect.

Comment: I had a feeling it had something to do with the `frame` property, but I wasn't sure how to implement it. I will try the code tonight and mark your answer. thanks.

Comment: Worked perfect!! I left out the last line and it went a little crazy, but as soon as I added it, it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An obvious way to do it is to store the offset of the touch from the shape's center in `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` and apply the offset in `-touchesMoved:withEvent:`.